# The html file restored after deleting in windows looks different. How to restore the previous format?

Tags: windows, file

I deleted my windows folder because of my inattention. I had important html files there that I didn't have time to push to the repository.

So I ran popular software to restore files (like CCleaner or Disk Drill), but the file I care about the most always looks the same (as in the photo below, this is the appearance after its restoration).

```
/@˙/s•  ˙/ro˙Đ#„„9i·•#˙/uâđ/yTOŰńfő #qvsđls˙/˙}
ń/.Ń5xppk zĐ8 qT xp 3p€z0}5»PVq Đ*‘‘37wĐbt    0Đ»~0U/-0 Nwp cmŇ-lń| P±d‹°t±3'đ  EPundĐŽ™
ż0o3?l˙}±=?Ueµ??“í?lĐ“s·oµ?5  1 7p˝So0'ń4q5p5r8t5?Ů5˙´˙´ ]d2 5w5Ż5@˙5s5•  55peúođŁsđµ˙´˙´˙´:ď:s5u5ś|5˙´ń©îc2Ť˙´q)tp,ŃR˙´4t ˙4_¸˙4g ˙ő4ńa´‘1Ó;´Q6?1ý?1e5?1´?1?1_“?1?1»g?1cspż0AÓ@}´q0ń0Řp´ę9ô0˙0˙0˙0˙0á– { ´˙0˙ó0•   ˙0˙0˙0P‹˙0±QźŐaffffc ű0}y´`´pM7_.^.oµ  p _ k z  f 8 q x p3 Hz g 5€ c - 0   SŘ  ** € ř  :h 0 dcQ#“×  ŘP&ˇŁ& : 2    A    4  >  â
'   Y 
   F —Č!  łm 
‚@q  Éá" k <3  Ä  ™ 9   ˛dF©: żc{Gé  M i Ýr oD s€f t€tWQ€    n d€w€
-P S e€t‚
g€y n€;čÖ ŁH5W ekodt·$/ "D€0b u€µ€ë8p1÷  zH  „ ¦S 7 E€Gp€r a€FiQ€n  €Ot€r€e€X €Úo rU€p€
c€ça€)eE„t€- m€cck€‡x.€k€2Aa[Ŕ_‚,@Ĺ%O@eŁŔG%F l@g@Ň:Ŕ 4 AI@A9˘vBe T@uŔ©Á$d Á fŔl@Şe |i@eŔo@Z¶eŔZÁ4eŔGA'\ŔŞh@2lŔ\@oŔ
]Á4n@:ÁÉjsÄNh@KsŔH\Ŕi b Á   CUAA.e .UŔpŔ2 Ân@ P 2 9Ä˝sŔ…S+Á»Á˝h Ž;Ä˝?Î&$˙˝ { Ń˝żĎ˝EŐ˝E&˙˝` t &ľi 0˙^?h-h÷^ňŕ^"L mS PbCT ×!>ˇ]eas`s Aĺ`®f <˙^ď^tâeŕ>Şu`Icŕa 
e`J5aA_  w 
ˇcb Ę3 l8 Gb a!˘® `!…cow`[t Ş `Fx` 0j   H¨  Nŕ
w [c [!Xc+ â! l 
rD '`  Eŕ.dŰ  áws`ˇaFŕ aëˇaTcäu"áZcŻcec%aco``aŕ_·ˇ+'?%p˘m!xd˘?-ql1 7 6l 4B·#Sákál   <äl~á˙l÷˙ËáĐńlżđË%ől%?˙lâ&˙Ë¤d–˙Ë- ×?Ő!Ő÷l¬ělC
±/}QYC%*ńW‘;Ń' Őp2a0"kĐ&g0 ×S]etUńł[pĐ[rÝhŃ%uf8˛4˙5ŞeĐ20˛?SPa0ÚF’.C”2Ó=6ź6k?2˙ceP.lp`‘a˙2q˙clóF?2“j?2?2ľlpÓ>_5Ń?2cPÚp0Bl°>sh6h2WŇnq1ń1čŔ=ô1Ęń˙1  ˙—12˙—˙—ű—‹ !Pś  r˙ř—˙1ó—•    ˙1˙—0ý˙1o°!rw&—u‡˙1'źś˙1źśc ű1ő Ľ“™  Ş pýCp _/12_/_/_/o_e[e˘P@  ńqĺpP>uPU%˙†˛¶—{§P@~˙s• 0u÷±8¶ođ®»»S<űPu¶”pPő¶¶¶_¶¶q¶˙†˙†ep»yop†˙†·ŮŔF0MqsűrS·cp4··ż…·ďS·Ń”QˇtpV±L·ď14?y·1qdń/q0qâ?t0<Ď&000MpL2 ˙ć őć   ý·@0s0• 00ď00Ň_·˙ćĐźëźS.0p0$µ     ö L S P :    T h e 8s y n c$e s i oQ D  f r \pT a >k 
g bs t t - mT i 2r Ns f 2. v p 9Q 
i d Fo x5 .e Qs -Ys  _ 8 w k {b 3 )8 b q- 0 s/?dU w 7t ­  xE 0
  - #N w c ›l lQ 1n g h nE _l€6r '€n ´ E€Ed€‰vF€U €#n€c€rĹ€u€p \€–é,\ wa‚}1
şe€pt„9…§… \€FŞo€’a€s€(t€Zi€@g€)Ľp‚(vë€xr€6l€>dŁę.€/p€» €1-ë€1 7 6 4€ü €8eh  **   Ŕ@h„   Öá&“×€†Ř&€ˇŁ&  €  Ť  ‚Ä    Ŕ h Ŕ@Á D 
Â    @ E –Ŕ F@Ă! @łÂ @E  Éá"Ŕ<3  ÄH  E& A  @˛d F©:żc{Gjé€/M@JcÂLEť-¬ WŔÁyoŔ•s@„
SJZSÄ¸;čÖ ŁH5Wekodtw/ D@b u@™ë@8p1÷  = ¬ ° SÉŮC@*e@‘íAĚCŔuÁeŔkÁ‹ĂŮ{˙×ÁnŔ“Cîß×áS`aŕPF`r C‡ŕkˇ#|= 0 /m˙dd+_dĄidío-Ńqd6 2$dsábácĘđ€UAäc$â˙c˙c#aińcŹ ! l  ţrčc%őc%˙c˙c ‚?e&˙c?m#;% ëcőŕĽ“™ @‰a‘"ţ •żĘĄżĘˇ_˝Ę…ŤWâÖá<á= ŠBä=DĽa'˙ˇ˙ˇ :ń=«đˇż%ő=%˙=˙=˙ ˙Pżý|źUźUŃ˙PőPđPëU!ŃuppSrňPu†…Úrđ  ez‡a0V±z•‡o0OopŠt "eLQ‡y‡,  «pSyO*ePap   -“
FĐu±sň“4 ]ŃI‘`Ń{c
T­u0‘drf°ęle@qi±yq_Ő1`oĐe0da°?†»?†=Nh°[Ń1†iđ“_1Ó3QO PO9[^ń0pń/q0Pp0Cńt0š<)0˛†°  súń0@0s•   0ű2oR!ß+ß+Ń+0O0†YźOg {Ţűp0˙· !‘ ©0»0˙·.đŹ‘¦±¬t¶˙p·¶¶ß1ą¶¶qŻ¶WĹ?„?0eP2lP°ű¶¶cPŚ¶Ý2?„×¶ű‰?„c:pPB“/}¶P#q4ueDô4RZ˙4¶ł¶˙4˙4{¶e ţ@˙4ó4•   ˙4˙4˙4˙PZ¶±ĐU0˙4˙4˙4˙4Ľc eye¶ŃZeĐ¬ćo2$¶c ěěńdîwr[4˙ę0r^˙´˙´˙›ëż0ż0ż0?ç—ä˙´’g0µ t i n g s y pc p  r o v i d e X\ lŃ <c a s DÄÄ. Šp   b¶e 6 2 4  i  **   Ř  Eh   Z)“ ×  Ř&ˇŁ&  B        ˘      
'    : 
 D F w ! E X rm  @q p Éá"€5 < 3  Ä‡L 
 ˛d F©:żc{TGé cM€’c‚—sE€‘f€Ą- W€  n€ťo w€©- SŠ™S„˛;čÖ ŁH5Wekodt·$/ D€0b u€áő Ľ“™  •  \ }Ťp€Ýc kU€g€s€Ra€eĐ - mŽ_.@-Az‚l@
t _ 8Ŕ‚eŔy b 3@5Š8ŔbÂ- 0FµP€[ ÁsÁuđ@S2FÄudÓ˙u×u“ô! AgłČuEŐuE&ë˙uBHtB{g@yCĎ˙uEËuë8p1÷b @t  € ÉE   µŔťp@"r@wÁ"oŔđ* ŔťtŔrByd h  f@    rŔ‚k[ŕW1A, eO`e« bˇLi n€plŕĄaŚ:ŕ4 ˇI «!W!Ťc T u"VeŕLáf`l e]ŕi`‰ááeŕ‹oU e`^a`
\`hŐ l`\ŕoŕ![»ˇšaeŕ ĺ4Ąśhŕű!aˇ›i`Zá#8çcńh2 9ä^yá\á]h  Gä]DW.Ď˙˙ •ń    ď]%˙ő]%˙]"'˙ŁĹe=˙]W?˘ă.÷]öŕ]L lSâ âŚ T ˇ=ˇ\#ő!e`@s`qă_˙]3źŞe Am Id    aŕ Zx"hn`ăXs>˘ W ˇżaX ŕ¤i hQ`^0 xŕF0j  Ń °  N Qw #ěVl áV `a`ydâ^r '`  Eë"!ĘsfF ˇµ!Şn cŕ    rŕ u `úp`Ŕs˘%c€ź]4ż‚ż‚ó"ß…Ó…?6 Ŕ 1 7 6Ô‚Uń5q6   Ht6\l6˙‚˙‚ 5[2 ˙‚đ„ó‚Ăe@˙6ó‚• 6˙‚6Ż˙‚q 6˙‚ođ]t°$_ź‡™O•6ue°|6CŐAeP$tĐ$C01$˙±WQ s6˙dź…•‘…˙5w±˙5‡w0‡qaS‹đ_±1F0 r C”2˝łŤ=6ź6?2˙ce6ölđ2ŃŻa’‘ń˙c3Gż?2“jß±?2?2?2o¸m?2 đ1ő´lq1ń1đŐŔ­Iô1T˙1˙1˙1Ł˙1h Ź˙´@˙˙1ó1•  ˙1˙1p˙1˙1ű˙1˙´opR˙1źąśű1=ů´tĐ—˙´÷‚˙´t Ý_/e`_/¶b°hU/y…¶p qńqÔJůôőí˙P˙˙˙˙č «˙P@˙ó˙• ˙˙˙ ˙˙˙}˙dĐ˙˙óÓy¶÷đPUS¶n0{ł¶QwQQ1iđV"‡dŻŮ"˙·ÁF°Ma2ţńSř·Tµ  e v i c pT r u s t Xd :  @ f a l De F Śl \  oT n c r uQ „p \ Fh lU Z\ Šo *m bnT g6e ¦tsÄ y ‚c h ‚Öâ\ 3i b'Ša…. —p p ‰
l=e    2 9 0  S   **  h Kh{1“ ×  Ř&ˇŁ&  B        ˘€ €€ 
‚ U€
  „€ @     ! €
ł,‚
 @…8  Éá"€5<3   Ä  …L !  €˛ dF©:żc{¨Gé _M€oc‚śŠs€‹f€~- W‚yŠd€w€Ż- S€°jt€i€źg€–; čÖŁH€5Wekodt·$¨/ D@bŔ€g€N€ë8p1÷ €B(  ö SL@S şPÂ…T@oÁbĹr Ŕ'şeŔ s@,Á‡AŽo@3Ş ŔnaŔpkŔgŔGv- Á‡K<. wÂp@mDe xŤ@<e@<Ĺ_ 8Â  ‚kŔ‘b 3 dŔbŔŹÁ- 0  UŔn@eŔ  @
iŐŔh@0@0ŔÉ ¨  -@NBX Ŕ)ëA»CšgŔhŔ AÁ˝r 'Ŕ7  E@"~d@BI;˙ĆÍĆE×ÁĆoÝÄ%sŔ5GE^pÂŚAđŞdŔr@Ńl@3c@.Ăí_ql1 7 6Ä 4"Yo sákál    LälĎ˙l˙láqńlĂďl%˙ől%˙lb&˙l˙l?v)źVS$ź÷l°ělC eŰ`9!˛Cŕ:á«eŕAáEĺălp c ˙k!Š˙k×a
ýkáÂSbRn@˘ˇ|ZC aŕb#|=`lx˙` kmd˙Çă1%_ddGdŁjqd6 2$di«ábácđ€ÂMäc]˙c˙Đ€Ż ńcŹ !ń Ů  rčĐ%őc%×˙c˙1ROoĐTsShînđ hQ…rP+ź6ź‘‚˙1qhőĽ“™´  { \C_e§P012_et _/eR˙_e_eYe˘P@ rvqńĺń‡Nôd“˙P‡‡ p2 ‡ ę s‡«˙P@˙s‡˙• ˙‡_Đs_Y˙g˙Ś˙Pc ˙Pu‡WđPU!‘§pr˛imn0z…r!ó~fýprpQĄ""qL«‡Q8P‡b01e01X0 ,Pµ
O*eWP41“
FP®aĐ°sőň“4ŇI…—Ń{˙·k˙·˙·e°ša°˙·a˙ň•ń±YUQ˙·•Wš­O POő·éů·Ot0xî6˙·˙·˛O˙·g0¸0w0’ BH¨| Yäpp ×ő·•   0˙0Đ#ßJ00˙·p“ĐßźĽTU#0u0ňp0˙·ßQ·3Ŕ˙·0ÓytźRP(îoŢs01v30“¸‘)e.µ"_p^w 5ŐĐ`102P7x0ŤÖy20ż·tp ·ż·ŃŤ3~ P…dP3~ep4ż·ŐŔ…‰1l˙±±h1ż·ż·ťż·źż·ó•5˙5  ą·ËôĄů·Pt6#6˙f˙fýf1µ@    :     FA 8ż!   łh@#6 “×’BH ¨| Yp ×<3  Ä   PhVr   l˛d F©:żc{ Gé  M i  c r o s f t - WQ n d w -P S e tg 
y n 3;čÖ ŁH5W ekodt7I/ D ab u g  ë8p1÷  z  ¬ L€8S P :   C€Te a€F˘e€o l€ e€EEMo€J  p€cÔ k€g€)s€- m€_‹t. w‚i3 2€e bÔ v€e€h€}"_€-w 5€,1 ‚h€t x y€+˘w€- 0‚IS€Şa€F€r€Jh€=Şn€de€ť=€x€Ş0ŠF€2l€" €Şn€c‚e€a€_Z\Ŕ
h@Á6\BfaďÂ.ÁÁÉbsŔ!ÁbEj\ŔCoÂ#l@Q
pKBÁ9dŔr o.UŔpŔ) ŔiŔ=euŔe6ŔF4ĄŔ@5    **  čU  QDˇdD«€t Ř&ˇŁ& D  
  {  Ä   D Ŕ  Ŕc@Á  
Â   ŃÇ‹„ !@  r€»Ŕ€ @EŐÇE& ˙Ç=IZSÄd˙Ç%  ëcő Ľ“™ @%  0ő'ŕ a 2ż^á{ż^c˝^ă+  uá;á<ĺŕ=Rä<ŹŕŁ’˙<Ŕ?÷ ;˙<é §đ %ő<%˙˙<bc˙ ˇ^˙ ?Ş-Ş÷ ®”€fĄAˇ†pŕlrŕŚçž#ťr"Łd   ľfbŠ˙ˇ)ż?C=C, µĺO Re *áŻi jn Ůl`g “aą4ş ˇI ˇż!’c ŞT u`t`dâ«ţf`Ł™˙¦˙¦c7ĺ¦ĺĽýˇ iŕżá«ŁŰă)ˇńť 2 9 0Â`c Wŕ|á_á`pŕ`Sä`ÂlwA˘ó˙`   ˙ť ÍŔđPó€˙€0ó€• 0˙€đ0oýqsđ˙€˙€˙€ź…ź…·ł0ő€üp0ů€TPyŰńgő #qwsvó€ß0u0.(oŇr0)p ń hp€±zlp 1‚ 0±”eUđ” đi:hP20«[0P-0 N°jwp cr/l‘ [Q†dPwQ5' t Eđwdđ‘9_2oű05ß…l°Ń?ß…uIUoß…ß…“ß…lĐ“s=tĐ8ß6  Ŕ1 7 6 ó…ro+q6ń6(đ6Tô6Ä~B˙6˙…2†˙…˙…ű6Éýg@˙6ó6• ˙6˙6˙P˙6˙6‘ őU˙…źĽźĽŮźŠc ˙6ő6¶ü6˙·Ýq¬cR˙·Q)tP,QTÝ˙·t4ó·6e°c6{ź¸±şyIź¸ź¸70ýiiň41uź¸Ń`eó+ß±ąż2ź/ź/oÇź¸×ż2Vż2cpp°BSBŻ›¸9ń1q2ř@±Ut2ü
2¸ł¸22{2ú•¸@2s2•   2ż22ęS2ęop’ßiiÓM{2y¸z‚É¸ß/Wˇ_feîµ  r e p .  c h x a °p _ hw 5 n 1 ¨2 t dy św y -( 0  k Ľg  eř  ** €    Vh  >ÓdB“×  ŘP&ˇŁ& : 2    A    4     "
'    ‚: 
  F ż ! E  sm  @q’BH¨€| Yp  ×<3  x‘™ O  ˛dF©:ż c{Gé  M i€}r o Šs€f€|- W€ (n d€w€
- ŞS€„t€i€Źg€y€c ;čÖ ŁH5Wekodt·$/ DA€0b u g ť… ćˇ–©ˇ‚X  źŔUB;Ń`z¸p °˙˙d    A˙˙/€F€!€=€jD C€_l l€,c‚]o€ZI€j
 ř @
AA
A[D
B
u@
t 
  €l  V€`hwLFt@‹eÜ mŔ@… :Â…Á‡Ę€"WÄ‡ś‹˙‡×‡±! AyłÇ‡ĂEŃ‡Ä  E&˙‡;Ŕ?˙‡s@ÚSšË‡ë8°p1÷ŔpŔ[ž ŰŞSŔčnŔ° Ŕ{p@"ZrŔčtŔiÁ{ ŔŻtŔr@€eŔ~  fŃ@    r   ~a`äy5¤t - 9-b. uë>. 
p ?‰/‰,«`%O`eŕ‘aćS*FŕUa `s€  ´4 ˇI ácv`ęc T u"!€MŐ`aŕs`F`!^Őa!nŕc˘e káśZ\ h ˇb\ oµŕm n aeŕ«!'ás¤*h sŕÂ\ i b áăŰˇ!eb©á! bá@  2 9 ä¦ á`áa°  Xyäa`ľ˙a˙ĄáŞńĄS˙đa%őĄ%˙ab'˙Ą˙ĄŢc?    h2ĺF÷a@˙aŕ  öa a]d`Qĺa7›?V­'V8?V"[f Ol Qje€Űi Fe áueí`ro ?Vg"Q?V?V7Qń+iq*ń*ŘH  Yô*Ŕż˙* > ˙}1+˙}Ác˙} őő}y˙*@˙*ó}•  ×˙*˙}R<oBtPV˙}?yU&˙}ź‚źźc «˙*ő[fđ*C…ER!¶NP
ńGf°Gł3 ň ő]| üX-0-qMqx_`‚n˛S Y NĐ} O P E R €A T I O0¨F LĐ GP=W˝mYqTQ2V °Lşx0 0: ßVż+eĐ-¶l°*–a˛eÓVcpZopYdP0óT\°l­upjŐWegZ>e0?ů­_X5 >7p­ˇ‰đśń,q-p  Zt-˝dD«ź-˛«--{«‰ó-  q‰•   --űđXođ!ß„-«2Ź°°-u- P%ęS0%PŇ'Tr˘Ńłő‘ es°sŠ‰pĆoŃ‹Q(‰tpw}‰curUl#gĐŐ~_Îhűz]Î °qż“’±ń­ëż/Q0 pD Đ3±13«u Đa+d0.ęeĐ\' P7±žęsđ inß_PQ•ęupp/sr˙Šß_÷3ŹńŠo5•‘÷©•Rp  o Q•dprĐŃ7±”7 ´ 1đ66pD7oq6•ń60đ6[ô6űy˙6ëdâ đß2 dwdúÍd@˙6ó6•   ˙6˙6đ˙6˙61N˙6˙6ożi°!çS3˙6ő6şpdZLĐ6SĐ]ńZC°e0$‘3|ŕ¶  o n   p@ a c k Pg@ e s t HtA H- m i dr śs f d. wQ Ln d <w ¬.Q >a l i –g- "h ra ®p "_ >w 5 61 h 2 ‚x y B‚w 
- 0 : "SCn F Sr ZC 'aK‹= #xU 0
F l E  1n c9e u‘ ąp \…\ ˝˘aÉn ge …VtĹWy€5c€@oU€e€l€%c€#l«€"‘p‚(v€d€<Vr°™p€Ž „šee€6€Ť4  Ş-  S0  **   ř  \h €
LzD“ ×  Ř&ˇŁ&  B€       ˘€ €€ 
‚ U€
 €_Ŕ€^ ™ !@  r,Â @E’B H¨| YpŔ×<3  DÄG& Â€˛dF©€:żc{Gé€1MŔJcBME‘- WoŔG‘Ŕ;ŔRtŔeC‘S@‡nŔd;čÖ ŁH5Wekodtw/ D@
b@g€NőĽ“™ €J  ~DöŔcÁlB5oÁÂN W@ĄÁ{Á} N]Ä}â†ô˙}×}µ! ˇ7ţłč>%ő>%˙>˙>¨q˙>?H+Hë>ë8p1÷  >  ˘€hëĺ
ápŕCrŕ~!ă˘#ˇrŕeŕť  fO˘Ś˙Ą˙Ą˙Ąn óĄ,«`…ĄO`Veŕ+a ęi`nŔxl áOáŞt4 ˇIŕa_!–cµ`T u`!ĽdâŻ~f`Łť˙ŞĄ»˙ŞăŞh«ŕá(\bťb Ąsd{Ł+ˇńˇ2 9 0_Âbˇ¶ áaáb ŕb^ńäbwE˙ˇ˙ˇ žńˇćżŕbŔ« ±čb%ńbpx  %˙b 0oĺ 0o Jt ˙ˇŁ)˙ˇ·?   #   ÷b¬p1ń/e6q«_ußcđoĐUd0
m\đ±tu°35eżr}:‘v?ůU!(0€4 7 6 )Đ#VS,bHT&.Đx­0 !°#701FĐ 1 3 4 8 `B E Ađ ń1(»
ł‹eĐ30đşFp7U±D¨  Rđtr°jHp(P)P9qCdŞ Ń
dđ8˛8rŞ4P FpŤDP 4 şC27lP±Q0xP<h: [0A méđ=t Ő>AĐ
1q<jt04]
2px–hq1ő1_ô1ů˙1k˙‚˙‚ 12 ˙‚9ö‚Ăc˙1  ˙ń1•   ˙1˙‚2˙1ô‘RçńôAĐc ˙1ý«˙1Ż%‘‡˙1uc°đ1CPÚE˛SNP
Qf“gÚ poĐ0ń©c“Y¨  b°"oĐłsVrP2»Ą-P2oPŞau„sđ%gĐŞÓ¸-Ż’q!‘'Ń-x0"-Q6rRlnR
S Y N°&O Pđ/‚R0T I O0¨F LĐ Gđ=đ1_łq'Ń±Q1 đ+xWP.Ń1±,fdđ1iďP±«ßB?¸ođ.ŃÄŃ}źAcP/ß@ßBFßBp×013q  2pÇ70 B2Aő1p  `ô1dĽ˘F˙c˙´2µ˙´0µó˙1÷1˙1˙1ó´ż•  ˙1˙1˙12$˙1gĐ˙3Y˙1˙1źą™*ŐH˙1ő1jüđ1LS°&Ń#T×đÜŃ5` ˛/sP •1Ż•č}
čc&pđ6Úup6eP1kR1?č˝;č P±ČSžńít0×S/au  °z p3‘<[Ń2ąď P‘ëdr1rô '0 đ6±QF7˙–ÓçźvźvńCpUđyq–o ±˙ë3 řë¶  e r \ l@ o c a ps t t i n@ g s y cD p ”o v TdŐÄ. ´p T  ÄR e   1 7 P6 4  c.p   **  ( ah0l˝F “×  Ř&ˇŁ&    B        Ť     
'    : 
   F ÉČ!  łm 
@q’BH¨|  Yp × <3  Ä     …L   €˛dF©:@żc{Gé _MU€|c‚s€”f€Ź-D W€ n d€wQ€“- SŠśS„ś; čÖŁH€5Wekodt·$/ D€0b u€Ë ë8p1÷˘  z  ¶ ¦L€?S P ‡  C€TŞe€ćt€C€Ol€ĆVe€Řęo€ç €ÜaU€k€gŔsŔ3aAŔ e - mN:.¬ wJ:Á~a@t@"*r@pBk@r "_@w 5Ŕ1 ¨h 2ŔxŔAe@ŞyŔ0B'SŔa@jF@&rŔ*h@!ÁšeA@Q= 0 xŔ 0UĘ F@lŔ @nµŔcBeŔÁ!\Ŕ
Öh@A9\ÂhaB1ÁýÁe@!ÍłEoľ˙ĘÁĘľ6ŔFCĘŔ\ÁÇÁÉř ­bÄÉĹ˙ÉŘÉ• !ń@Ű  rČÉ%őd%˙˙db0˙d#Ś˙d? +   ëd€őĽ“™ @Š¨  z eŔp NÜc ż_á|ż_iŕYż_Î- Z ‹G <3á=á>    cä>3ŢG˙Ł˙Ł ;ńŁżŕŁŔ­ś ±č>%ń>x'˙>˙>(q˙>˙>ů>éŁ¬·ŕŁáža o ?‡g`âµaŘo`Śdŕ‹Łŕ\ =­!ĺu ľ%ăe ™gŕ“Çá’ýĄć( 1ŕäˇĺ¶)ŕóĆH`śá˛. ›Zx` !ŕGŁ˘7@ÝF`í1 3 8 B E Aŕ:  Ü ( ˇřˇĄr˘­%©QŻ4 8 Ę)PR#đÓ\n Hđ( ¬9 qQSd01đV7Đ18r4P FŐ°[DĐ 4 CP51XUgne\t0[Ő0A’epYp µ®AĐ
1q…tpb]f
2py
hq1ń1  dô1=˙1k˙˙ 12 ˙ú ő±đ1Q€ů˙1źó•  ˙1˙2o ˙vsĐq nđ˙ńFrűź0opvźŐ˙ő®žđ1U1vpđ rĐW±ó‚‚r°ep wq4„tR„źTs6 „źTn2„0 Ö,"O°eP+Śęipnđ1lpŃ«11ş4ŇIP<ń“±&cđ
ZTu01’d’2fŐ0leđi“˙†ż˙†‘˙†‘ń‡UBhňęt0l°Bbp •“WQŐA9µ2801t¬ .q0ń0đ0eô0|Žž˙0˙0˙0˙0˙b4 »˙0@˙0  ßńb•  ˙0˙0Ro˙0P˙˙´3X˙0˙0źą9 u#˙0Uő0¨đ0Cđ´Er!N[P
ńfJg p9o"QVc01S'  b[0%38e ťÔ-pak0Ô‘3i’4uP'-[ňc1 rĐd±
-*x×p-Ńf1¶rđ.o~.Ń- S Y NXO°żE R`T I ˘O0F LĐ Gp¶=pb3m2e˛
¬  ń¶7]f
d˙/ëQu2p˛+˙¶“ýpcđźt_s›vů1Ş Đł5o5’1lń0q1xp1ft1'›Kż”ć˛ććA˘bvbüć1sb• 1˙1đßŹß]FŐ,111e¶ t i n g S y pc /  D e b u ë8p1÷       L śS P  :   T h± ¤  sre  s i o –  
f r Rp a ¨c k 
g bs ć‚a e - m +¨c r 's f . w n d Şw M. 9l u  e x p Ar !*e­e o %t ˘_ 'w 5 1 Ş2 Ix —e My gÖ0 …1d =d c˘t '  0€)0€E‰ €  N‚@ ±€+a l€ “ €Şa€2d€e€\'€>¨  E‚S€.s€UF€Rl€ €#nU€c€r€u€p\ \€ź,\‚€a×‚†Ĺ
e€`t€ «…°… \€=o„Ks€(k‡â…p‚(v€xrë€6ˇc€<l€;‘-MµÁ]p@[ ŔA>e@M€1 7 6 4Ŕ‚   lx  **  8Ŕgh   K˛K“ ×  Ř&ˇŁ&  "   ‘  Ä  ”     Ŕ@Á  
Â    @  šŔ FA@Ő! @ł,Â @E’B H¨| YpŔ×<3  Ä  E& A  @
˛d F©:żc{4Gé€/MŔIKˇ- vWŔGˇ-Ŕ˝IMEË; čÖŁH€5Wekodtw©×ÝÂËÝCŔve@rÚt@~CŔ”Ae@A‹;ĂÝ˙Űoŕ!G˙mn «óm!„SbTn€7o`ćC$gc€= 1off?ătf­kf=qf6 Š2$f8`‘e káeÓáfŔ` häfś˙f˙föfˇ ! o  rčf%őf%˙f ;!°oí ˝tŕ¦˙fn B˙f?pńŐőĽ“™ éa+ †"`żĎżĎżaąĎ€ŽB ˇ$ ˘á? Ĺ Źiä?h.L˙¦€—a§˙¦!
:€ ă¦ćÁŕ¦€ ±č?%˙Ŕ  x  •   ˙S0Hő_1q_†˙iP!y€źź‘$SőŠ®ŻpSńP±QńGe0MaĐ »źw™wc˛uŃ†D\ ×5±„gbe°u?«ůUA(R4t)0‹ßŃH˛t .°]Zx0 !PR“‰7PTFĐ1 3đD8 Bm0‡Ađ qV(
3ŠeŹĐ8ŐŚ_4 8ž )   Rđt0šr°‹Hpń    0 ‘©qNd ń d82Š8’4P F Cv 3 C°h1h±hn«P‹Qšt€{[PARŚÚeŤp UsAđ
1Őń‰tPš]°
ő1q1ĺő1jô1±3˙1…ł…­˙1°……v…˝đ1˙}…˙1s…•  ˙1˙1˙1˙Ö­…SM˙1˙1źVŠ˙Ľý÷ĽŞđ11Ş“µ‘ąő»µ“şre˙Ľa0Âýżt Ń˙Ľ‘,˙ĽŐ4o˙Ľ˙Ľ˙…óĽ,0#ŐOGP=‘/·F l0 g´ sp( đ2ŃIĐ «±ÍQ'c°/T0/u0ő‘drf0ó±Dúe0l0.QKż»ń-ą»öh”=±»iđŐQHł÷Đő˙ Đ907Á1tžő1   kô1P×˙1˙1˙1 p2 ˙1ő÷1µ˙1@˙1óc• ˙˙1˙1˙1˙1˛VWę˙1˙1Ż˙1˙1˙1÷1˘đ1CpżîE˛!Ńŕ1fđJ¦‘áÖo2 Ű·bp%o°ž‘ŮVrđ%Ys’f0ií+ađ°qĽd0q(ű±Xń-đ)±·‘21ăQôFo^.‘^S YęC O PaR AUpůIĐ NđbLĐ Gí=0Ó
m01é±Đňµ    0 x 8 P0 4 Pf c  d F i lD e čo n c o r u a  p \ s hU 4l Ś\ .o *mQ bn g 6c *oD u Šs y zcU&e 2gfe.Ő “p w  Yi 7— 2 5 7    a we s @ **    lh ´®M “×  Ř&ˇŁ&     !     € €F€ 
‚D €
  :€  ‘ Á!a€  ±6 @…8’BH¨| Yp€×<€3  x  …LH ‚' ˛ dF©:żcP{Gé _M€Śc‚¬s€Ľf t -T W‚–d€w€ż-´ S€Ŕt€g€µ;čÖŁ H5Wekod˘t·$/ D@b@rg€Në8p1÷â  ?  ® S˙…˙…Ĺ…( 1Ŕ®7 6¬ )Ŕ’ÓEHŔMs@KŠ.Ŕ4xŔ ! 0D Š7€rFŔ’1 3@€8 B E AŔj:@ż(@ža@ťÁÂrŻ€~AËĂ
O
4@ŃD@ ¨  RŔtŔMrŔŞVH@qÁ'1BtŔpdj Ád@8ÂÇŢF´ CŔ\ ŔĂ CŔŐUÁŘCŔ.nŔ.e@ętU@![@9AŔtŔmµŔĹtFAŔ+ÁvŔęt@ß]Ŕ
‚™ŔćÁĹ‹ÁÇÁÉmÄÇŁ4N˙c·˙c`ińcąŕcˇ\łčc˙%őc%˙c˙cb$˙c?mVe0  ÷c¦ŕcC`2Em"FN 7a2fŕ1c U 4o¤Jc iâ; ¬ b"ˇ{e s˘H+!áŞs €fŕr jm u žgŕ!Z-Ż`=ŁCáM!- xŕBVlâa   p r J!
ˇwá[S Y ˘N NO P ^Rŕ^ T I O`F ęL G = b#aM˙!aáNˇˇaÇÇÇëÉ'Ç!&a-e }Çr ‚oĺĆ€  näb<ăĺ˙b˙ĆáËńb#ś! íb%ńbÄ'Ż˙b˘H˙ĆcQSP)nđ(ťciPĐĐ&o hń(źV‘1ucUP%S0%P’1TR„ łk‘ p|đ 1/ µ°,aĐkĐ+U/ap3e01±#c. wż1•r ń.Q+q2dp0Şlvň0yđ4apZQ3„r _pwp…nQ0eh 2PxeU0yĐ1 pnŐĐŤe0  ˛tpł0«5eu  0 Đ4op714łd“ P‘d uÓe'p P8±‘s×vßßePlpa~a0
3‘šąK™59\˝Poq  ýF3p˛[ńdqrQEcl{đ żc°18 k°Ńz4’irq7qi@Ĺđ7oô7Ű+Oi›Ű˛››°››pťs›śÝ˙7˙7  ń7˙•   ˙7›ĐV˙71 _3˙7ý›o˙7° ˙7ő7jĘpiLĐ7SĐ^ń[C˝°e‘11†±†eĐ ëb7tÔ-&7Q'»7ńZt3771p1Ő75CS˛*n›0ćC43A= ‘Ě8ż3˙ż3ż3ńcż3óż3ź0“żż3ż3s:u9ż3 P®>2yˇ3Ô7q3ń3Č  pô3",˙3ĎuĎ ś2 ˙3÷3©Ä !0  rxť˙˙3ó3• ˙3˙3˙3Đ#˙3Q˙3˙3˙3ÔÔű3@őĽ“™ bŢŽËĐĎˇEpP0c ßh_1Ntđ‡ßhßhi ßheĐ9ßhÝh"T@   2+ńq  pTqt j‰ y                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               </td>
                        <td>Vertical gap between items</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>caption</td>
                        <td>
                            'pushTop'
                            <br>'pushDown'
                            <br>'revealBottom'
                            <br>'revealTop'
                            <br>'revealLeft'
                            <br>'moveRight'
                            <br>'overlayBottom'
                            <br>'overlayBottomPush'
                            <br>'overlayBottomReveal'
                            <br>'overlayBottomAlong'
                            <br>'overlayRightAlong'
                            <br>'minimal'
                            <br>'fadeIn'
                            <br>'zoom'
                            <br>'opacity'
                        </td>
                        <td>'pushTop'</td>
                        <td>Caption - the overlay that is shown when you put the mouse over an item. <br>NOTE: If you don't want to have captions set this option to an empty string (e.g. caption: '')</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>displayType</td>
                        <td>
                            'default'
                            <br>'bottomToTop'
                            <br>'fadeIn'
                            <br>'fadeInToTop'
                            <br>'sequentially'
                        </td>
                        <td>'fadeIn'</td>
                        <td>
                            The plugin will display his content based on the following values.
                            <br>- default (the content will be displayed without any animation)
                            <br>- fadeIn (e.g. lazyLoading) (the plugin will fully preload the images before displaying the items with a fadeIn effect)
                            <br>- fadeInToTop - fadeInToTop (the plugin will fully preload the images before displaying the items with a fadeIn effect from bottom to top)
                            <br>- sequentially (the plugin will fully preload the images before displaying the items with a sequentially effect)
                            <br>- bottomToTop (the plugin will fully preload the images before displaying the items with an animation from bottom to top)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>displayTypeSpeed</td>
                        <td>only integers, values in ms (e.g. 200, 300, 500)</td>
                        <td>400</td>
                        <td>Defines the speed of displaying the items (when <i>displayType: 'default'</i> this option will have no effect)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            lightboxDelegate
                        </td>
                        <td>strings that represent the elements in the document (DOM selector)</td>
                        <td>'.cbp-lightbox'</td>
                        <td>Define any clickable elements you wish to use to trigger lightbox popup on click. </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            lightboxGallery
                        </td>
                        <td>true or false</td>
                        <td>true</td>
                        <td>Enable / disable gallery mode for lightbox popup</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            lightboxTitleSrc
                        </td>
                        <td>HTML atributte</td>
                        <td>'data-title'</td>
                        <td>Attribute of the delegate item that contains caption for lightbox</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="color: #D66767">lightboxShowCounter</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>This options is deprecated. Please use lightboxCounter option instead</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            lightboxCounter
                        </td>
                        <td>HTML markup code</td>
                        <td>
                            '&lt;div class=&quot;cbp-popup-lightbox-counter&quot;&gt;{{current}} of {{total}}&lt;/div&gt;'
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Markup of the lightbox counter. To hide the counter for lightbox put this option to an empty string (e.g. '')
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            singlePageDelegate
                        </td>
                        <td>strings that represent the elements in the document (DOM selector)</td>
                        <td>'.cbp-singlePage'</td>
                        <td>Define any clickable elements you wish to use to trigger singlePage popup on click. </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            singlePageDeeplinking
                        </td>
                        <td>true or false</td>
                        <td>true</td>
                        <td>Enable / disable the deeplinking feature for singlePage popup</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            singlePageStickyNavigation
                        </td>
                        <td>true or false</td>
                        <td>true</td>
                        <td>Enable / disable the sticky navigation for singlePage popup</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <span style="color: #D66767">singlePageShowCounter</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>-</td>
                        <td>This options is deprecated. Please use singlePageCounter option instead</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            singlePageCounter
                        </td>
                        <td>HTML markup code</td>
                        <td>
                            '&lt;div class=&quot;cbp-popup-singlePage-counter&quot;&gt;{{current}} of {{total}}&lt;/div&gt;'
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Markup of the singlePage counter. To hide the counter for singlePage put this option to an empty string (e.g. '')
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            singlePageAnimation
                        </td>
                        <td>
                             'left'
                             <br>'fade'
                             <br>'right'
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            'left'
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Defines which animation to use when singlePage appear
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            singlePageCallback
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            function(url, element) { <br>
                            // to update singlePage content use the following method: this.updateSinglePage(yourContent)<br>
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>null</td>
                        <td>Use this callback to update singlePage content. The callback will trigger after the singlePage popup is open. (@param url = the href attribute of the item clicked, @param element = the item clicked)</td>
                         <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript: void(0);">7</a></li>
                  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript: void(0);">8</a></li>
                  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript: void(0);">9</a></li>
                  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript: void(0);">...</a></li>
                  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="javascript: void(0);">394</a></li>
                  <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="javascript: void(0);" aria-label="Next">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div> <!-- container -->

      </div> <!-- content -->

      <!-- Footer Start -->
      <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <script>
                document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
              </script> Â© Konektia - Wszystkie prawa zastrzeĹĽone.
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="text-md-right footer-links d-none d-md-block">
                <a href="javascript: void(0);">Wsparcie techniczne</a>
                <a href="javascript: void(0);">Wyloguj</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
      <!-- end Footer -->

    </div>

    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- End Page content -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->


  </div>
  <!-- End -->

  <div class="rightbar-overlay"></div>
  <!-- /Right-bar -->

  <!-- bundle -->
  <script src="{% static 'assets/js/vendor.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'assets/js/app.min.js' %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Is there any way to restore the file in classic form or change these unusual characters to correct HTML code? I tried to change the UTF encoding but to no avail (I use Windows 10).

How can I restore a deleted file in the correct form or change the html file restored to the correct form?

Answer (score 0):

> So I ran popular software to restore files (like CCleaner or Disk Drill), but the file I care about the most always looks the same (as in the photo below, this is the appearance after its restoration).

According to me you didn't permanently delete the file right? cause whenever a file is deleted it goes to the recycle bin...you could've easily restored it from there, but now there is no reason crying on spilt milk.

I think this should work as I have never seen this error...ping me if this works or not!
`right click` on the file, go to `properties` and then click on `previous version` and then if there is a previous version then jump in the air and yell hooray!

[This link might help you!](https://superuser.com/questions/1358869/txt-files-how-to-switch-from-weird-characters-back-to-normal)

That's all I have, welcome.

Comment: the history of the previous versions is empty. The file has been removed to the recycle bin and the recycle bin emptied. The file recovery software has restored it

Comment: @MaddieGraham usually when a file is permanently deleted the file is over-written with other data, so basically the file might might not be able to restore to the original point. But if this helps then try going to the file, then go to `file` > `Save as` > and then try changing the file encoding with all the available options, and check all the files made, usually the change of file encoding from for example UTF-8 to ANSi etc.. will result in success.